# Bluetooth controlled bot code not understood

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, arduino-uno, robotics

I am making a Bluetooth controlled bot but I am not able to write the code.
So I searched on internet but do not understand why can't we use output of "Serial.read()" directly instead of using a char string to store it's value as done in the code below?

Here is the code I saw(from circuit digest):
There are 4 wheels and hence 4 motors.

```
#define frm1 2         //front right motor
#define frm2 3         
#define flm1 4         //front left motor
#define flm2 5
#define rrm1 6         //rear right motor
#define rrm2 7
#define rlm1 8         //rear left motor
#define rlm2 9

char str[2], i;

void forward()
{
  digitalWrite(frm1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(frm2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(flm1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(flm2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(rrm1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(rrm2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(rlm1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(rlm2, LOW);
}

void right()
{
  digitalWrite(frm1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(frm2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(flm1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(flm2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(rrm1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(rrm2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(rlm1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(rlm2, LOW);
}

void backward()
{
  digitalWrite(frm1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(frm2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(flm1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(flm2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(rrm1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(rrm2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(rlm1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(rlm2, HIGH);
}

void left()
{
  digitalWrite(frm1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(frm2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(flm1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(flm2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(rrm1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(rrm2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(rlm1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(rlm2, HIGH);
}

void hault()
{
  digitalWrite(frm1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(frm2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(flm1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(flm2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(rrm1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(rrm2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(rlm1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(rlm2, LOW);
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(frm1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(frm2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(flm1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(flm2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(rrm1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(rrm2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(rlm1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(rlm2, OUTPUT);
}
```

This is the loop I don't understand.
What is the use of string here and how does str[i-1] help?

```
void loop() {
  while(Serial.available())
  {
    char ch = Serial.read();
    str[i++] = ch;    

    if(str[i-1] == '1')
    {
      forward();
      i=0;
    }
    else if(str[i-1]== '2')
    {
      left();
      i=0;
    }
    else if(str[i-1] == '3')
    {
      backward();
      i=0;
    }
    else if(str[i-1] == '4')
    {
      right();
      i=0;
    }
    else if(str[i-1] == '5')
    {
      hault();
      i=0;
    }
    delay(100);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no purpose in the use of the index variable i.  First, in str[i++] = ch, the author increments i after storing the character in str[], and then immediately references the added character using str[i-1].  Then they set i=0, which clears the buffer which was never used in the first place!   Here is a better way:

```
void loop() {

    while (Serial.available()) {
        switch (Serial.read()) {
            case '1':
                forward();
                break;
            case '2':
                left();
                break;
            case '3':
                backward();
                break;
            case '4':
                right();
                break;
            case '5':
                hault();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        delay(100);
    }

}
```

Note that the loop (like the original) will exit as soon as serial data input stops.  That may or may not be desired.

Note also that you may want to double buffer the input from Serial.read() to avoid dropping characters at higher baud rates - however, the original code was not doing that:

```
void loop() {
    char ch;
    char str[16];
    int i, j = 0;

    // buffer up to 16 chars
    while(Serial.available()) {
        ch = Serial.read();
        str[i++] = ch;
        if (i >= 16)
            break;
    }

    // process buffered characters
    for (j=0; j<i; j++) {
        switch (str[j]) {
            case '1':
                forward();
                break;
            case '2':
                left();
                break;
            case '3':
                backward();
                break;
            case '4':
                right();
                break;
            case '5':
                hault();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        delay(100);
    }
    // reset buffer
    i = 0;
}
```

The reason for a 16 character buffer is that common UARTs buffer at most 16 characters.  You can, of course, adjust the size.

Comment: Thank you! That really helped!!